# Tag synonym request: [soft-link] -> [symbolic-link]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Could I ask for another tag synonym for symbolic-link, that is soft-link. Reference [Wikipedia Symbolic Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). I don't have enough reputation to work with tags yet. I came across this because I am new to Ubuntu. In working on a problem I read articles referring to soft links as opposed to hard links.  When I went to tag my question with soft-link I was surprised there wasn't one.  So then I had to research more and finally learned that a soft link is another name for a symbolic link.  Adding this additional synonym will help other newbies.  Someone with a 2500 reputation (required for a tag) would probably never consider this. They'd know to use the symbolic link tag.

Comment: You need 300 for creating tags, 2500 for synonimising tags... And 2500 rep users can only synonimise existing tags

Comment: Well, I think that this is a worthy tag and synonym to create.  Newbie's as I who encounter the term soft-link first, won't know that it is a synonym of symbolic-link.  Having the soft-link tag as a synonym will direct newbies to symbolic-link thereby increasing their knowledge as well.

Comment: Note that *soft-link* isn't used as far as I know. [It's "soft link"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soft+link%2C+soft-link%2C+symlink%2C+symbolic+link&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoft%20link%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csymlink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csymbolic%20link%3B%2Cc0), two words, not hyphenated. Quoth the pedant. And yes, I know this is a pretty irrelevant point to make since the tag would have to be hyphenated. But pedant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable request. If you were confused by this, presumably others might be as well. I've now created the [soft-link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/soft-link) as a synonym of [symlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/symlink).

If you now try to tag something with [soft-link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/soft-link), it will be tagged with [symbolic-link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-link).

Comment: doesn't symbolic link refer to both hard and soft links? Should we also make a synonym for hard-link?

Comment: @ravery no, symbolic links are symlinks, and are also called *soft links*. Hard links (the default action of `ln`) are different. See `man ln` or [the relevant Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).